# crispy error |as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I want to customize the django Model field according to my needs and submit the data into database.
I did all the things accordingly. But after running the app i getting the crispy error. I can't able to find my errors. 
Please help me friends.

Models.py is as follows

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from configration.models import AddSite, AddDepartment, AddCategory, AddDesignation, Rate
# Create your models here.


class EmployeeRegistration(models.Model):
#Departmental Details

EmpId = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='EmpId')
Site = models.ForeignKey(AddSite,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=150,verbose_name='Site')
Department = 
models.ForeignKey(AddDepartment,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=150,verbose_name='Department')
Category = 
models.ForeignKey(AddCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=150,verbose_name='Category')
Designation = 
models.ForeignKey(AddDesignation,on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=150,verbose_name='Designation')
PfAllowance = models.BooleanField(default = True)
EsiAllowance = models.BooleanField(default = True)
Uan = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = False,verbose_name='Uan')
Pf = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True,verbose_name='Pf')
AttendenceAward = models.BooleanField(default = True)
AttendenceAllowance = models.BooleanField(default = True)
ProfesionalTax = models.BooleanField(default = False)
Rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True)
# Personal Details
Name = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Name')
Father = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Father')
Dob = models.DateField()
Gender = models.BooleanField(default = True)
#Female = models.BooleanField(default = False)
MaritalStatus = models.BooleanField(default = True)
Address = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name='Address')
Aadhar = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
pan = models.CharField(max_length=10)
choices = [('Working','WORKING'),('NotWorking','NOT WORKING')]
Status = models.CharField(choices=choices,blank = False,max_length=10,verbose_name='Status')
Doj = models.DateField(default = date.today)
Doe = models.DateField(blank = True,verbose_name = 'Doe',null = True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{name}'.format(name=self.Name)
```

views.py is as follows

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .regform import regisForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from configration.models import AddSite, AddCategory,Rate
from .models import EmployeeRegistration
# Create your views here.   
def ids():
   no = EmployeeRegistration.objects.count()
   if(no == None):
      number = 1
      return number
   else:
      number = no + 1
      return number

def registration_view(request,*args, **kwargs):
  emp_id = ids()
  EmployeeId={'EmpId':emp_id}
  form = regisForm(request.POST or None,initial=EmployeeId)
  print(form)
  if form.is_valid():
     form.save()
     form = regisForm()
  else:
     pass

  context = {
    'form':form,
    "contact":"active"
   }
return render(request,"registration.html",context)
```

registration.html is as follows

```
{% extends 'profilebase.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content%}
<div class="content-section">
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/register/"> {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset class="form-group">
      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Register
      </legend>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{ form.EmpId | as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Departmental Details
      </legend>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{form.Site|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {{form.Department|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{form.Designation|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {{form.Category|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {{form.Uan|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{form.Pf|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {{form.PfAllowance|as_crispy_field}}
          {{form.EsiAllowance|as_crispy_field}}
          {{form.ProfesionalTax|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Personal Details
      </legend>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{form.Name|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {{form.Father|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{form.Dob|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {{form.Gender|as_crispy_field}}
          <!--{{form.Male|as_crispy_field}}
          {{form.Female|as_crispy_field}} -->
          {{form.MaritalStatus|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {{form.Address|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          {{form.Aadhar|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          {{form.pan|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{form.Status|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{form.Doj|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{form.Doe|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
      </div>

  </fieldset>

<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="Submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

[image: Screanshot of error which i got during running]

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
def registration_view(request,*args, **kwargs):
  emp_id = ids()
  EmployeeId={'EmpId':emp_id}
  form = regisForm(request.POST or None,initial=EmployeeId)
  print(form)
  if form.is_valid():
     form.save()

  else:
     return render(request,"registration.html",{"form": form, "contact":active})   #add this

  context = {
    "form":form,   #edit this
    "contact":active
   }
return render(request,"registration.html",context)
```